# Can someone help me find this Minecraft mod name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, mod-identification

[image: screenshot of mod]

I can't seem to find the name of the mod in the above screenshot. If someone knows about this mod, please tell me the name.

The screenshot is from this YouTube video:

Answer (score 3):

Those feathers indicate available dodges from the [Elenai Dodge 2](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/elenai-dodge-2) mod.

The blue feathers are available dodges, which the silver ones indicate how many are restricted by the armor you are wearing.